# What is the issue with this function?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, function, return

I created a function to recall the amount of posts in a certain category, in a forum. Here is the code for the function:

```
function num_posts_evedisc() {
    $sql3 = "SELECT COUNT(category) FROM forum_question WHERE category=3";
    $query3 = mysql_query($sql3);
    return($query3);
}
```

And this is the response I got, echo-ing it:

```
Resource id #14
```

(In my database, I have table forum_question and the column category. I tried replacing the (category) with (id) and that didn't work either.)

Thanks!

Comment: It's a result resource - you need to get the data with `mysql_fetch_array` or similar.

Comment: The mysql_* extensions have been deprecated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mysql_query` returns a [*resource*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php), which in turn gives you access to the result. To access the result, you have to use something to get information from the resource, such as:

```
if ($row = mysql_fetch_row($query3)) {
    return $row[0];
}
```

(You can also use other functions, like [`mysql_fetch_array`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) or [`mysql_result`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php).)

Note, though, that the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and will be removed in a future version of PHP. Look at [Mysql Improved Extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MYSQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php).

Comment: Thanks that worked. Also, I know they are deprecated, I just will update everything once I've finished most of the site.

Answer (score 1):

```
return mysql_result($query3, 0)
```

is what you need to return

Comment: :) yes, and then rewrite is using PDO.

Comment: Not seeing why this isn't getting upvoted more, maybe it's the lack of explanation. Anyway, +1